# Can anybody explain in detail for WP -> this.CordovaView.Browser.LoadCompleted += Browser_LoadCompleted;?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

For hybrid cordova Windows Phone application `this.CordovaView.Browser.LoadCompleted += Browser_LoadCompleted;` code is used. Can anybody explain this in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoadCompleted event is an event, which is fired when the Browser control is loaded in the view.

```
 this.CordovaView.Browser.LoadCompleted += Browser_LoadCompleted
```

Here, you are attaching a listener to LoadCompleted event, so whenever the browser control will be loaded in view, the event LoadCompleted will get fired, which will eventually call your method Browser_LoadCompleted.

Apart from this event, whenever you try to navigate a url, the default webBrowser control will fire following event.

```
webBrowserControl.Navigated += WebPageLoaded;
webBrowserControl.NavigationFailed += WebPageLoadFailed;
webBrowserControl.Navigating += WhileNavigating;
```

Navigating event is fired when the browser starts navigation and depending upon whether the navigation was a success or not, either navigated or NavigationFailed event will be fired.